# is there a way to avoid cmake adding "\ " when I have withespaces in a string?

Tags: cmake, whitespace

I have a list of strings ***ARGN*** that I get from the parameters of a function defined by me. I want to use those strings in the list to build a string that is going to be used in one command, I do the following in order to achieve that.

```
set(excludes )
foreach(XFILES IN LISTS ARGN)
  string(APPEND excludes "--exclude ${XFILES} ")
endforeach()
message(STATUS ${excludes})
```

The string printed by the message command looks fine

> --exclude '*.h' --exclude '*.hpp'

however if I use the variable *excludes* as part of a command, I see in the resulting build.make file that the withespaces are somehow escaped with a "\ " and because of that the program processing the string fails

> --exclude\ '*.h'\ --exclude\ '*.hpp'\

I have found other questions already asked where this cmake behavior also causes problems, however non of the answers that I've seen helped me. **Is there a possibility for removing those "\ " inserted by cmake?**

Comment: Maybe instead use `list(APPEND excludes --exclude ${XFILES})`? But I'm not sure, it may introduce extra `;`

Comment: You create the `excludes` variable as a **string** which contains **spaces**. So CMake preserves these spaces in the COMMAND you use. Instead, make `excludes` variable to be a **list** of values, as suggested above. So CMake would treat every value to be a separate argument in COMMAND.